# Avoiding global state when depending on a fixed source of information

Tags: python, singleton, system-design

I have a single source of information in my project (structure of directories) that I am parsing into an object. The directory structure will never change while the program is running and it's object representation will also never change. At the moment it's a single variable but I'm trying to expand the while project into something more robust and I'm running into different system design questions.

A singleton *seems* to me like a good pattern to use here (despite nearly opinion I've read so far) because

1. It's state will never change while the program is running
2. There will only ever be one instance of this object throughout the program.
3. It's referenced very widely across the codebase.